# Why are my models not showing up in django admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have made alot of models and forgot to register them when I made them, after I realized I didn't register them I went and registered them the usual way (shown below). I've deleted the database and all migrations (including `__pycache__`) but haven't deleted the `__pycache__` in the inner project folder (that holds `settings.py`) because I don't know if that would cause problems or not. I've tried using `admin.register(Comment,admin)` but that didn't work and, as you know, isn't necessary. I'm not sure what other information I would need to give so please let me know what else you need to know. Just so you know, I have `'django.contrib.admin'` and `'django.contrib.sites'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` and also have `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` in the project level `urls.py`

```
admin.register(PicturePost)
admin.register(VideoPost)
admin.register(TextPost)
admin.register(Comment)
admin.register(Report)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code because you are not using correct method to register the model. admin.register is method decorator for ModelAdmin class.

```
admin.site.register(PicturePost)
admin.site.register(VideoPost)
admin.site.register(TextPost)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Report)
```

Comment: Somehow I didn't remember this, Sorry for being such a noob and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[`admin.register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) is a decorator that you should apply to custom `ModelAdmin` classes - not a function that you can use to register models.

You need to use [`admin.site.register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.register) instead:

```
admin.site.register(PicturePost)
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you, somehow I didn't remember to use the site. Sorry for being such a noob lol